# Differential geometry/fluid dynamics derivation

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, fluid-dynamics

When two scalar functions (stream functions) $\psi_{i}$ are are producing two surfaces, $\nabla\psi_{i}$. The surfaces are intersecting in a line given by $\alpha\vec{v}=\nabla\psi_{1}\times\nabla\psi_{2}$.
This leads to $\nabla\vec{v}=0$.

I have found $\nabla\vec{v}=0$ can be shown by a direct calculation. Is there a more elegant proof?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Are the scalar functions $\psi_i:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$? What does it mean for two functions to intersect? Is $\vec v$ a vector field or a fixed vector?

Comment: Are the scalar functions ψi:ℝn→ℝ? yes
two surfaces intersect to produce line
Is v⃗  a vector field or a fixed vector? vector field

Comment: Thanks for the corrections